# How to format (as separate strings) multidimensional arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Current input:

`"[["a"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"],  ["a", "c"], ["b"],["b", "c"],["c"]]"`

Expected output:

`"a ab abc ac b bc c"`

*not `["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "b", "bc", "c"]`*

How can I join and display them as separate strings

Comment: It would help if you showed the expected output as formatted code. Is that supposed to be `"a ab abc ac b bc c"`? Or `["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "b", "bc", "c"]`?

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what do exactly you want. Array:

```
array.map(&:join)
#=> ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "b", "bc", "c"]
```

String:

```
array.map(&:join).join(' ')
#=> "a ab abc ac b bc c"
```

Comment: From _"display them as separate strings"_, I think OP wants `array.map(&:join)`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, I think so, but who knows :)